# Refreshing ListView in Android after receipt of an SMS doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to refresh a ListView onReceive of a BroadcastReceiver. Within my main activitiy, which contains the ListView I'm talking about, I'm registering a receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver smsIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String mAction = intent.getAction();

        if(mAction.equals(INCOMING_SMS_ACTION)) {
            Log.v(runtimeVars.getMyName(), "reloading conversation list");
            curConversation = managedQuery(conversationURI, null, null, null, "date DESC");
            conversationAdapter = null;
            listConversations();
        }
    }
};
```

listConversations() looks like that

```
private void listConversations() {
    Uri smsURI;
    Uri personURI;
    Cursor curSms;
    Cursor curPerson;
    long personID;

    curConversation = managedQuery(conversationURI, null, null, null, "date DESC");
    conversationArrayList = new ArrayList<ConversationListObj>();
    this.conversationAdapter = new ConversationListAdapter(this, R.layout.conversationlist_item, conversationArrayList);
    setListAdapter(this.conversationAdapter);

    Log.v(runtimeVars.getMyName(), "listConversations");

    startManagingCursor(curConversation);
    for(curConversation.moveToFirst(); !curConversation.isAfterLast(); curConversation.moveToNext()) {
        smsURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + curConversation.getString(curConversation.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString());
        curSms = managedQuery(smsURI, null, null, null, null);
        conversationArrayList = new ArrayList<ConversationListObj>();
        ConversationListObj newListObj = new ConversationListObj();

        newListObj.setThreadID(curConversation.getString(curConversation.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString());
        if (curSms.moveToFirst()) {
            personURI = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(curSms.getString(curSms.getColumnIndex("address"))));
            curPerson = managedQuery(personURI, new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(curPerson);

            if(curPerson.moveToFirst()) {
                personID = Long.parseLong(curPerson.getString(curPerson.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID)));
                Bitmap contactPicture = generalMethods.loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver(), personID);
                if (contactPicture != null)
                    newListObj.setSenderPicture(contactPicture);
                else {      
                    InputStream input = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.person_dummy);
                    newListObj.setSenderPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
                }
                newListObj.setSenderName(curPerson.getString(curPerson.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            }
            else {
                newListObj.setSenderName(curSms.getString(curSms.getColumnIndex("address")));
            }
            newListObj.setMessagePart(curConversation.getString(curConversation.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet")).toString());
            conversationArrayList.add(newListObj);
            notifyConversationAdapter();
        }
    }
    curConversation.close();
}
```

Now, whenever I receive an SMS it seems as if my BroadcastReceiver was too fast. The new text message won't show up until I restart my app. So I basically think I made a design mistake, but how would it be correct? Looking at the logfile tells me

```
08-29 13:08:44.351: VERBOSE/SotapannaSMS(704): reloading conversation list
08-29 13:08:45.091: VERBOSE/SotapannaSMS(704): listConversations
08-29 13:08:45.921: VERBOSE/Telephony(171): getOrCreateThreadId uri: content://mms-sms/threadID?recipient=5556
08-29 13:08:46.081: INFO/NotificationService(59): enqueueToast pkg=info.SotapannaSMS.messaging callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43dbff88 duration=0
08-29 13:08:46.571: VERBOSE/Telephony(171): getOrCreateThreadId cursor cnt: 1
```

The new text message seems not to be within this conversation until I restart the app. I even tried to let my app sleep for 3 seconds to see if just waiting a bit would work, but that ended up in the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: not sure, but could it be that you're trying to update your UI from non-UI thread and therefore it does not get updated?

Comment: Actually I don't think that's the case. Both the BroadcastReceiver and the listConversations() method are located within my main activity and therefore should be in the same thread. Well, at least in my understanding... :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android stores the message only after your onReceive is finished.

If you sleep your onReceive call for 2 seconds, than the message gets stored 2 seconds later.
Spin up a new thread, and sleep there. Your onReceive should return ASAP.

Source: LogCat